# why background:url('') not working in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've used url() in my project, but it is not showing the picture in IE 6? does IE6 not support url()? How should I solve the problem?
The code is as below:

```
<img class="avatar" style="background:url('./avatar.jpg') no-repeat scroll 5px 7px transparent;" />
```

Comment: the given css/html isn't valid. Is this what you are actually using?

Comment: NOT actually is been modified and thing got wrong a little, I'll edit it in a jiffy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-image`:

```
<img class="avatar" style="background-image:url('./avatar.jpg')" />
```

Also note that you had an extra `)` at the end.

Also make sure that this is actually a problem with the background image. What happens if you set the background color? Do you see it then? It could be a layout problem that it causing it to not appear.

Comment: @علیرضا then perhaps it isn't an issue with the background-image. What happens if you set the background color? Do you see it then? It could be a layout problem that it causing it to not appear.

Comment: the problem has been solved by your suggestion to set background-color. I didn't specify width and height for my image and IE6 could not understand the pic.

Answer (score 1):

The entire tag looks wrong. I would do something like this:

```
<img class="avatar" style="background-image: url('./avatar.jpg');" alt="" />
```

I would also check that the path is correct.

-- Edit --

After testing, I've noticed that a path like `'./avatar.jpg'` will never work. It's looking for a folder entitled `.` in the same directory as the file you've written the style in. Do you have a folder named `.`? I don't think so. It's an illegal directory name.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your code should be strict, clean and semantic. Otherwise you'll create bigger problems for yourself later on.

Comment: what do you mean? If path is not correct how would it be possible for other browsers to understand where is the avatar??

Comment: I couldn't tell you. Maybe some browsers are designed to allow for incorrect paths. I've updated my answer, by the way.

Comment: They're not in the same folder, but for clarity I ommited the folder part here in my question.